# Как исправить ошибку ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, twitch

Программа работает, но иногда она может вылететь с ошибкой: "ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение" при работе, или при запуске. Как можно было бы это исправить? (Python 3.8) Вот мой код:

```
import config
import socket
import re
import threading
import _thread

def main():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((config.HOST, config.PORT))
    s.send("PASS {}\r\n".format(config.PASS).encode("utf-8"))
    s.send("NICK {}\r\n".format(config.NICK).encode("utf-8"))
    s.send("JOIN #{}\r\n".format(config.CHAN).encode("utf-8"))
    chat_message = re.compile(r"^:\w+!\w+@\w+\.tmi\.twitch\.tv PRIVMSG #\w+ :")

    while True:
        response = s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        if response == "PING :tmi.twitch.tv\r\n":
            s.send("PONG :tmi.twitch.tv\r\n".encode("utf-8"))
        else:
            username = re.search(r"\w+", response).group(0)
            message = chat_message.sub("", response)
            print(response) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Нужно узнавать у самого твитча почему его сервера разрывают соединения. Но вы можете в случаи разрыва переподключаться. Просто сделайте цикл, что вызывает `main`

Comment: Если не сложно, не могли бы вы написать пример такого цикла?

Comment: Ок, добавил в ответ

Answer (score 1):

Добавил пример цикла и отлова исключения:

```
...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        try:
            main()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"[-] Error: {e}")
```

Если нужно выводить трассу стека ошибки, используйте модуль `traceback`

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @NameBulist, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)